# How to change variable of a stateful widget from another widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, delegates, widget, flutter-layout

How to change a variable of a Widget from another widget?
This is the main stateful widget called `HomePage`:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  num counter = 0;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Title")),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [Text(counter.toString()), CardWidget()],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

This is `CardWidget` which is added to `HomePage`:

```
class CardWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CardWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CardWidgetState createState() => _CardWidgetState();
}

class _CardWidgetState extends State<CardWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        child: Column(
      children: [
        Text("Press the button to increment the counter"),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            //Something here to increment the counter in HomePage
          },
          child: const Text('Increment'),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

This is what is shown on the screen:
[image]

Is it possible to create a connection between the two widgets: if I tap the button something happens in the HomePage Widget? (similar to delegate in UIKit)

Comment: Please post your HomePage class also.

Comment: Use `ValueNotifier` and `ValueListenableBuilder`. Check out my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69807920/flutter-how-to-correctly-create-a-button-widget-that-has-a-spinner-inside-of-i/69924373#69924373).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `Function` parameter.
In your `CardWidget` add `Function` parameter.

```
class CardWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  //Add clicked function
  final Function onClicked;
  const CardWidget({Key? key, required this.onClicked}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CardWidgetState createState() => _CardWidgetState();
}

class _CardWidgetState extends State<CardWidget> {
  int _count = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        child: Column(
      children: [
        Text("Press the button to increment the counter"),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            //Something here to increment the counter in HomePage
            //Execute `onClicked` and pass parameter you want
            _count++;
            widget.onClicked(_count);
          },
          child: const Text('Increment'),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

then on `HomePage` add `onClicked` parameter

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  num counter = 0;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Fontanelle")),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
               Text(counter.toString()),
               CardWidget(
                //Add onClicked
                 onClicked:(count){
                    print("Clicked "+count.toString());
                 }
               )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some solution for this case:

1, Create [GlobalKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) for StatefullWidget, and you can access to State from HomePage

2, Create a [Stream](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams) from Homepage and pass to StatefullWidget

3, Pass param to StatefullWidget and use [didUpdateWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html) on state to listen.

Answer (score 1):

I remember that was my first question when did my first step in flutter, how say @dangngocduc is true but my advice is that read about BLOC

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc

This is very helpful to do this.